# Control space between paragraph and example environment - amsthm package

Tags: spacing, theorems, amsthm

Which parameter sets the spacing before and after of the example environment from amsthm library?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{example}{Exam}[section]

\begin{document}

  \section{My section}
    \lipsum[2] % Dummy text
    \begin{example}
       \lipsum[1] % Dummy text
       \begin{equation}
         x^2 + y^2 = 1
       \end{equation}
    \end{example}  
    \lipsum[2] % Dummy text  

\end{document}
```

Comment: `amsthm` has three different theorem styles, one of which -- `remark` -- has no extra space above and below.  it would probably be a good idea to investigate this before trying to change the predefined spacing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `amsthm` package offers three predefined styles for the theorem-like structures: `plain` (the default style), `definition` and `remark`; the `remark` style leaves less space before and after the structure than the other two styles, as can be seen in the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[hmargin=2cm]{geometry}% just for the example
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text for the example

\newtheorem{exai}{Plain}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{exaii}{Definition}
\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{exaiii}{Remark}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[4]
\begin{exai}
\lipsum[4]
\end{exai}
\lipsum[4]
\begin{exaii}
\lipsum[4]
\end{exaii}
\lipsum[4]
\begin{exaiii}
\lipsum[4]
\end{exaiii}
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

The internal lengths controlling the spacing before and after the structures are `\thm@preskip` (for the space before) and `\thm@postskip` (for the space after); in `amsthm.sty` one finds:

```
\def\thm@space@setup{%
  \thm@preskip=\topsep \thm@postskip=\thm@preskip
```

So the value of `\topsep` will be used for the structures built with the `plain` and `definition` styles; on the other hand, for the `remark` style, `amsthm.sty` has:

```
\def\th@remark{%
  \thm@headfont{\itshape}%
  \normalfont % body font
  \thm@preskip\topsep \divide\thm@preskip\tw@
  \thm@postskip\thm@preskip
}
```

so, for the remark style, half the value of `\topsep` will be used for the structures built with this style.

If you want to change the default value for the `plain` and `definition` styles, you could then use in the preamble something like

```
\makeatletter
\def\thm@space@setup{%
  \thm@preskip=.5\topsep \thm@postskip=\thm@preskip
}
\makeatother
```

A complete example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\makeatletter
\def\thm@space@setup{%
  \thm@preskip=.5\topsep \thm@postskip=\thm@preskip
}
\makeatother

\newtheorem{example}{Exam}[section]

\begin{document}

  \section{My section}
    \lipsum[2] % Dummy text
    \begin{example}
       \lipsum[1] % Dummy text
       \begin{equation}
         x^2 + y^2 = 1
       \end{equation}
    \end{example}  
    \lipsum[2] % Dummy text  

\end{document}
```

Of course, this will affect all theorem-like structures for the two styles `plain` and `definition`, and it will also affect the spacing after the structure, since `\thm@postskip=\thm@preskip`; if you want the change only for a particular structure, you can use `\newtheoremstyle` (refer to the documentation for 
 `amsthm`) to define the settings appropriately. A little example (using a space that is too small. but it is just for example purposes):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheoremstyle{example}% ⟨name⟩
{3pt}%⟨Space above⟩
{3pt}%⟨Space below⟩
{\itshape}%⟨Body font⟩
{}%⟨Indent amount⟩
{\bfseries}% ⟨Theorem head font⟩
{.}%⟨Punctuation after theorem head⟩
{.5em}%⟨Space after theorem head⟩2
{}%⟨Theorem head spec (can be left empty, meaning ‘normal’)⟩
\theoremstyle{example}
\newtheorem{example}{Exam}[section]

\begin{document}

  \section{My section}
    \lipsum[2] % Dummy text
    \begin{example}
       \lipsum[1] % Dummy text
       \begin{equation}
         x^2 + y^2 = 1
       \end{equation}
    \end{example}  
    \lipsum[2] % Dummy text  

\end{document}
```

Comment: When I use library \usepackage{parskip} the \thm@preskip=.5\topsep \thm@postskip=\thm@preskip doesn't work.

Comment: @jafan I did some tests and it still works when the `parskip` package is loaded; if it doesn't for you, you should consider opening a new question with this new issue.