# Using thmtools to make colored theorem style

Tags: spacing, color, theorems, amsart, thmtools

I am trying to define a new theorem style that is identical to the standard `remark` provided by the `amsart` class, except for its color. As far as I understood, it is a good idea to use the `thmtools` package. However, I do not know what options I should include in the command `\declaretheoremstyle` to produce the usual `remark` style from `amsart`.

Below is my attempt. As you can see, the result is not satisfactory because the vertical spacing before and after the remark changes slightly. Does anybody know how to solve this?

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{thmtools}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remark}

\declaretheoremstyle[headfont = \color{red}\normalfont\itshape, bodyfont = \color{red}\normalfont\itshape]{colored}

\declaretheorem[sibling = theorem, style = colored, name = Remark]{coloredremark}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
Body of first theorem.
\end{theorem}

\begin{coloredremark}
Body of colored remark.
\end{coloredremark}

\begin{theorem}
Body of second theorem.
\end{theorem}

\begin{remark}
Body of normal remark.
\end{remark}

\begin{theorem}
Body of last theorem.
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really need to use `thmtools` for that. Since you want a style similar to a default style provided by `amsart`, it's even simpler to use `\newtheoremstyle`, which is defined by AMS classes and by `amsthm`.

To see how to use `\newtheoremstyle`, see the section 4.3 of the [documentation](https://ctan.org/pkg/amsthm), on page 9. Here's an example that should work.

[image]

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remark}
\newtheoremstyle{coloredremark}%
    {}%
    {}%
    {}%
    {}%
    {\itshape\color{red}}%
    {.}%
    {.5em}%
    {}%
\theoremstyle{coloredremark}
\newtheorem{coloredremark}[theorem]{Remark}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
Body of first theorem.
\end{theorem}

\begin{coloredremark}
Body of colored remark.
\end{coloredremark}

\begin{theorem}
Body of second theorem.
\end{theorem}

\begin{remark}
Body of normal remark.
\end{remark}

\begin{theorem}
Body of last theorem.
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! Avoiding `thmtools` would be even better. The problem is that when I try to color also the body font, extra vertical spaces appear. One should thus set appropriate values for the space above and the space below.

Comment: Do you know which values I should choose?

Comment: @MK7 leaving the first two arguments blank (as I did in the example) will use the default values for the spaces above and below. Did you try as in the example?

Comment: Yes, I did! But I also need the body of the remark to be red. If I add `\itshape\color{red}` in the third argument and leave the first two blank, then extra vertical spaces appear. Am I missing something?

Comment: It works by adding `.5\topsep` in the first and second arguments. That is the default value of the `remark` style, as indicated in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/87524/153361).